# Swap Photo of two contacts via contentResolver update

Tags: android, set, contacts, photo, android-contentresolver

I want to swap the profile pictures of two contacts with each other **without writing any bytestreams**! I was wondering if it is possible to update the PHOTO_FILE_ID, PHOTO_ID, PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI and PHOTO_URI with the contentResolver. Is it even possible?

This is the code i tried (not runable, i just copied some parts of the total code):
This is how i read the information:

```
String[] projection = new String[]{ ContactsContract.Data._ID,
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.PHOTO_FILE_ID,
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.PHOTO_ID,
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI,
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.PHOTO_URI};

Cursor cursor = this.contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, projection, ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " LIKE ?",
           new String[] { ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE }, null);

if( cursor.moveToFirst() ){
    long ID = cursor.getLong( cursor.getColumnIndex(
            ContactsContract.Data._ID) );
    Integer photoFileID = cursor.getInt( cursor.getColumnIndex(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.PHOTO_FILE_ID) );
    Integer photoID = cursor.getInt( cursor.getColumnIndex(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.PHOTO_ID) );
    String photoThumbnailURI = cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI) );
    String photoURI = cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.PHOTO_URI) );
}
cursor.close();
```

and this is how i tried to write the information in another contact:

```
ContentValues contentValues =  new ContentValues();
contentValues.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.PHOTO_FILE_ID, photoFileID);
contentValues.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.PHOTO_ID, photoID);
contentValues.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI, photoThumbnailURI);
contentValues.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.PHOTO_URI, photoURI);

String where = ContactsContract.Data._ID + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " LIKE ?";
String[] params = new String[] { String.valueOf(ID), 
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE };

this.contentResolver.update(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, contentValues, where, params);
```

If i run this script, the debugger tells me that the columns are not valid...
any ideas how to update the photo-details in another way?

Comment: Paste the debugger output here too. It'll help others to understand the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is a confusing part of the Contacts database.

Even though the "photo" column *names* are inherited by ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName, those *columns* are not recognized for a StructuredNames row.

If you will update your post with the ContactsContract.Contacts columns you want to swap, I'll recommend the preferred way to swap the photos.